# Execute File from python

Tags: python

Im trying to make a python program, and i just can't find any information on Google on how to just execute a non-python file from python (with an if statement).  For Example:

```
if abc == "abc":
    "Execute ThisFile.sh"
```

EDIT: this was marked as dupe, but I am not trying to run a single command, I want to execute the entire file.

Comment: Well the question is very similar, as you are really looking for a command to execute a non-Python file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)  module.

```
if abc == 'abc':
    subprocess.check_output('bash file.sh', shell=True)
```